# How to show vscode debug console?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VS code extension and the log was output to Debug Console, but user can't see the log if they didn't open Debug Console, so I want to show VS code debug console, but I couldn't find the API to do that.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.debug.action.toggleRepl');
```

This can show Debug Console! But it will hide the Debug Console if Debug Console has already opened.

Answer (score 0):

If someone (like me) finds this question with a web search, I have an answer. On Mac, it can be shown with these two UI steps:

[image: View Appearance Selection]

[image: Panel Selection]

Sorry for the blurry images caused by significant size reduction.